# my php mail function working fine for all mail except my hosting email

Tags: php, email

I had transferred my hosting mail account to Gmail server.
my email id dummy@trustmedi.com. 
my PHP script sending mail to all other mail perfectly, but not getting any mail in trustmedi.com.
if I send mail from my gmail to dummy@trustmedi.com, it's working.
I had already tried gmail smtp, PHPmailer but it's not working.

Comment: Can you post the sample code you're using. It will help to see and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I can see is that your domain is listed on SORBS DUHL black list which says:

```
Additional Information: [Dynablock] Dynamic IP address, use your ISPs mail server
Listed but has active as exception(s) and therefore might NOT be blocked.
166.62.27.124 is an active exception for the network 166.62.24.0/22.
166.62.27.151 is an active exception for the network 166.62.24.0/22.
```

This, or gmail's rejection of the messages, could possibly be caused by the fact that you don't have a PTR record set.